# Extract Nested Json fields from Pandas DF

Tags: python, json, pandas

The JSON file I get is from below code:

```
import jsonpickle
import tweepy
import pandas as pd


consumer_key = "xxxx" 
consumer_secret = "xxxx"
access_key = "xxxx" 
access_secret = "xxxx"

#Pass our consumer key and consumer secret to Tweepy's user authentication handler
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
#Pass our access token and access secret to Tweepy's user authentication handler
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
#Creating a twitter API wrapper using tweepy
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#This is what we are searching for
searchQuery = '#machinelearning OR "machine learning"'  

#Maximum number of tweets we want to collect 
maxTweets = 1

#The twitter Search API allows up to 100 tweets per query
tweetsPerQry = 100

#new_tweets = api.search(q=query,count=1)
tweetCount = 0

#Open a text file to save the tweets to
with open('test_ml1.json', 'w') as f:

    #Tell the Cursor method that we want to use the Search API (api.search)
    #Also tell Cursor our query, and the maximum number of tweets to return
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=searchQuery,tweet_mode='extended').items(maxTweets) :         

            #Write the JSON format to the text file, and add one to the number of tweets we've collected
        f.write(jsonpickle.encode(tweet._json, unpicklable=False) + '\n')
        tweetCount += 1

    #Display how many tweets we have collected
        print("Downloaded {0} tweets".format(tweetCount))
```

I have a JSON file which you get when you download the tweets using Twitter API's. I have stored these tweets in a df using below code as the JSON has nested dictionaries([Loading a file with more than one line of JSON into Python's Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088006/loading-a-file-with-more-than-one-line-of-json-into-pythons-pandas)):

```
import pandas as pd

# read the entire file into a python array
with open('your.json', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# remove the trailing "\n" from each line
data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)

# each element of 'data' is an individual JSON object.
# i want to convert it into an *array* of JSON objects
# which, in and of itself, is one large JSON object
# basically... add square brackets to the beginning
# and end, and have all the individual business JSON objects
# separated by a comma
data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"

# now, load it into pandas
data_df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)
```

Below is the code for dataframe to csv which I get:

```
data_df.to_csv("output_batch.csv",encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Below is the screenshot of columns in csv:
[image]

**My question**

I want to extract "Screen_name" from the "entities" column. In the below example it will be "NIRAV_88".

Comment: Have you tried `df = pd.read_json('your.json')`? If that doesn't work, could you post some example data from `your.json`? The snippet of code that you're running was designed to fix a specific Yelp dataset, and I'm not so sure it's needed here.

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler: I was not sure how to give sample JSON, so added code to how to generate one. Also, this is the type of JSON you get when you extract Tweets from Twitter using Tweepy.  Yes, I have tried but I was getting value error: trailing error. I even tried df = pd.read_json('your.json', lines = True), but this also didnt work. Finally the code shown in the question only worked

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object. This is the schema for the tweets