# Extracting portions of JSON string column containing multiple rows and columns in pandas

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where `parameters` column is JSON and contains multiple actual rows and columns:

```
input_data = pandas.DataFrame({'id':['0001','0002','0003'],
                               'parameters':["{'product':['book','cat','fish'],'person':['me','you']}",
                                             "'{'product':['book','cat'],'person':['me','you','us']}'",
                                             "'{'product':['apple','snake','rabbit','octopus'],'person':['them','you','us','we','they']}'"]})
```

... from which I'd like to extract the following data frames:

```
product_data = pandas.DataFrame({'id':['0001','0001','0001','0002','0002','0003','0003','0003','0003'],
                                'product':['book','cat','fish','book','cat','apple','snake','rabbit','octopus']})


person_data = pandas.DataFrame({'id':['0001','0001','0002','0002','0002','0003','0003','0003','0003','0003'],
                                'person':['me','you','me','you','us','them','you','us','we','they']})
```

Below is how I've utilized Regular Expressions to get me there. I doubt this is the best way to do it but here it goes:

```
for i in input_data.id.tolist():
    s = ''.join(input_data[input_data.id == i]['parameters'])
    product_string = re.search(r"product':(.*?),'person", str(s)).group(1)
    product_data = pandas.DataFrame(product_string[1:-1].split(','))
    person_string = re.search(r"person':(.*?)}", str(s)).group(1)
    person_data = pandas.DataFrame(person_string[1:-1].split(','))
    print("........")
    print(product_data)
    print("........")
    print(person_data)
```

I'd like to learn a faster, more elegant, or wholesome solution that may capture unexpected nuances.

Comment: It helps if you say *"`parameters` is a JSON string column containing multiple rows and columns in pandas"*; I edited this and tagged [tag:json]. There are tons of existing questions on extracting/parsing JSON in pandas. Really you should start from doing [`read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) on your input JSON, not `read_csv`, to avoid ever having to manually extract this stuff. (Can you show us a snippet of your JSON input file? Without that link this question is not [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading a file with more than one line of JSON into Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088006/loading-a-file-with-more-than-one-line-of-json-into-pandas)

Comment: Duplicates like [Loading a file with more than one line of JSON into Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088006/loading-a-file-with-more-than-one-line-of-json-into-pythons-pandas), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037430/reading-multiple-json-records-into-a-pandas-dataframe). [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257147/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-json-format) and [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+JSON+votes%3A10)

Comment: Please read the [`read_json` doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the weird structure of the strings in row 2 and 3 and the final output desired below is one version:

```py
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'id':['0001','0002','0003'],
                               'parameters':["{'product':['book','cat','fish'],'person':['me','you']}",
                                             "'{'product':['book','cat'],'person':['me','you','us']}'",
                                             "'{'product':['apple','snake','rabbit','octopus'],'person':['them','you','us','we','they']}'"]})

input_data['parameters'] = input_data['parameters'].str.replace("'{", '{').str.replace("'{", '{').str.replace("}'", '}')
input_data = input_data.join(pd.DataFrame(input_data['parameters'].apply(literal_eval).values.tolist()))
```

### Get length of objects for later input ids

```py
products_len = input_data['product'].apply(len).values
persons_len = input_data['person'].apply(len).values
```

### Spin each result as separate `df`

```py
## flatten x into a list of dictionaries
values = input_data['person'].values.flatten().tolist()
flat_results = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist]

## reinsert a and b
person_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_results, columns = ['person'])


## flatten x into a list of dictionaries
values = input_data['product'].values.flatten().tolist()
flat_results = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist]

## reinsert a and b
product_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_results, columns = ['product'])
```

### Append back the ids:

```py
## person
ids = input_data['id'].repeat(persons_len).reset_index(drop=True)
person_df = person_df.join(ids)

## product
ids = input_data['id'].repeat(products_len).reset_index(drop=True)
product_df = product_df.join(ids)
```

### Result

```py
person_df
Out[57]: 
  person    id
0     me  0001
1    you  0001
2     me  0002
3    you  0002
4     us  0002
5   them  0003
6    you  0003
7     us  0003
8     we  0003
9   they  0003

product_df
Out[58]: 
   product    id
0     book  0001
1      cat  0001
2     fish  0001
3     book  0002
4      cat  0002
5    apple  0003
6    snake  0003
7   rabbit  0003
8  octopus  0003
```

Answer (score 2):

First, setup yor products and persons using [`str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) accessor

```
input_data['products'] = input_data.parameters.str.get('product')
```

Now, for **pandas `>= 0.25.0`**, you may use the `explode` method

```
input_data.explode('products')
```

for pandas `<= 0.25.0`, you may refer [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939)

---

I assumed you have dictionaries in your data frames, and not *strings* as you exposed here.

If you have strings, you may always

```
import ast
input_data.parameters.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

to make them real dictionaries.

Comment: `input_data[['id','products']].explode('products')`

Comment: input_data['products'] = input_data.parameters.str.get('product') creates the column with each field being 'nan'. Is this expected?

Comment: input_data.parameters.apply(ast.literal_eval) yields invalid syntax error

Comment: Reading JSON is a job for `read_json`; recommending `ast.literal_eval` is total overkill. The OP should never have read in mangled JSON via `read_csv` (or whatever) in the first place.