# How to skip duplicates and blank values from JSON dataframe and store into an array?

Tags: python, json, pandas

The following code displays data from a JSON Line file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy


start = time.time()
with open('stela_zerrl_t01_201222_084053_test_edited.json', 'r') as fin:
    df = pd.read_json(fin, lines=True)
    parsed_data = df[["SRC/Word1"]].drop_duplicates().replace('', np.NAN).dropna().values.tolist()
    
print(parsed_data)
```

The output is:

```
[[' '], ['E1F25701'], ['E15511D7']]
```

Is there a way remove the blank data, duplicates, and store it as an array?

[image]

Comment: [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove duplicates, [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to filter out blank rows and [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to convert to a numpy array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.dropna()`,`.drop_duplicates()`.

```
parsed_data=parsed_data.drop.duplicates()
parsed_data.dropna(how='all', inplace = True) 
# do operation inplace your dataframe and return None.

parsed_data= parsed_data.dropna(how='all') 
# don't do operation inplace and return a dataframe as a result. 
# Hence this result must be assigned to your dataframe
```

If directly `.dropna()` not working for you then you may use `.replace('', numpy.NaN,inplace=True)`.

Or you can try this too:

```
json_df=json_df[json_df['SRC/Word1'].str.strip().astype(bool)]
```

This is faster then doing `.replace()`, if you have empty string.

And now we cleaned it, we can just use `.values.tolist()` to get those value in list.

Comment: dropna doesnt work says it doesn't exist. The replace method have the output blank.

Comment: @minTwin I had already told you, `inplace=True` doesn't return any values!

Comment: I get the following output: [[' ']
 ['E1F25701']
 ['E15511D7']]

Comment: parsed_data = json_df[["SRC/Word1"]].drop_duplicates().dropna(how = 'all').to_numpy()
 
Produces the result. The data all has to be in a single array.

Comment: There is an error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_list' if I change to_numpy to to_list()

Comment: It is outputing multiple arrays. Is there a way to make all the data be stored in a single array?

Comment: What does that mean? Example please!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235159/discussion-between-mintwin-and-xitiz).

Comment: @minTwin do this `json_df=json_df[json_df['SRC/Word1'].str.strip().astype(bool)]`

Comment: @minTwin According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56708633) doing `.astype()` is faster then any other.

Comment: @minTwin you are telling that you get many array, does this solve your that problem? `prased_data=[[' '], ['E1F25701'], ['E15511D7']]
print([a[0] for a in prased_data])
`

Answer (score 1):

Yup! Pandas has built-in functions for all of these operations:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('stela_zerrl_t01_201222_084053_test_edited.json', lines=True)
series = df['SRC/Word1']
no_dupes = series.drop_duplicates()
no_blanks = no_dupes.dropna()
final_list = no_blanks.tolist()
```

If you want an numpy array rather than a python list, you can change the last line to the following:

```
final_array = no_blanks.to_numpy()
```

Comment: The following gets an error: ValueError: Trailing data

Comment: @minTwin Ah so this occurs when your JSON file has more than one JSON block in it. A separate issue from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088006/loading-a-file-with-more-than-one-line-of-json-into-pandas

Comment: @minTwin Fixed my answer to use `lines=True` to prevent that error

Answer (score 1):

Drop the duplicates, replace empty string by `NaN`, then create the list.

```py
>>> df.drop_duplicates().replace('', np.NAN).dropna().values.tolist()
[['E1F25701'], ['E15511D7']]
```

**PS:** Since what you have is a dataframe so it will be a 2D List, if you want 1D list, you may do it for the specific column:

```py
>>> df['SRC/Word1'].drop_duplicates().replace('', np.NAN).dropna().tolist()
['E1F25701', 'E15511D7']
```

What you have is not an empty string, but white space character, Try this: replace `\s+` to `np.NAN` with `regex=True`:

```py
>>>df['SRC/Word1'].drop_duplicates().replace('\s+', np.NAN, regex=True).dropna().tolist()
['E1F25701', 'E15511D7']
```

And apparently, below will also work:

```py
df['SRC/Word1'].drop_duplicates().str.strip().replace('', np.NAN).dropna().tolist()
['E1F25701', 'E15511D7']
```

Comment: This output is: [[' '], ['E1F25701'], ['E15511D7']] is there a way to put all the data into a single array?

Comment: Can you add the output screenshot to the question along with the solution I have provided? That shouldn't be the output.

Comment: Sure one moment

Comment: Okay, I saw it, that is not an empty string but space character, try the last solution in the answer with `regex=True`

Comment: Produces the same output

Comment: `df['SRC/Word1'].drop_duplicates().replace('\s+', np.NAN, regex=True).dropna().tolist()` copy this code and run it on jupyter notebook.

Comment: This one should definitely work: `df['SRC/Word1'].drop_duplicates().str.strip().replace('', np.NAN).dropna().tolist()`